# js does not work - Controller and js file

Tags: php, javascript

I try to solve a problem , but it does not work. In controller,

I have this code,

```
public function sendFeedbackAjax() {
        $feedback = $this->params('feedback_textarea');
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $to = 'sinemalar@nokta.com';
        $subject = 'Sinemalar Görüş Bildirimi';
        $message = 'URL: ' . $this->params('url') . '<br/><br/>E-posta adresi: ' . $this->params('feedback_email') . '<br/><br/>' . $feedback;
        $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" .
                'Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"' . "\r\n" .
                'From: noreply@sinemalar.com' . "\r\n" .
                'Reply-To: noreply@sinemalar.com' . "\r\n";

        $uid = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . 20;       
        $user = NCore::cache()->remoteCache->get($uid);



        if ($user != null) {
               $this->sendJSONResponse('Error');
        } else {
         NCore::cache()->remoteCache->set($uid, $ip, 60 * 60 * 24);
             mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
            $this->sendJSONResponse('OK');

        }
    }
```

It checks cache server; if there is key there, it sends   `$this->sendJSONResponse('Error');` else it sends   `$this->sendJSONResponse('OK');`

but in JS side I try this:

```
$.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: '/json/common/sendFeedbackAjax',
            data: "action=send&url="+url+"&"+values,
            success: function(response)
            {
                if(response == 'OK')
                {

                    $('#feedback_body').html('<p>Görüşleriniz alınmıştır, teşekkür ederiz.</p>');

                    setTimeout(function () {
                        hideFeedback();
                    },2000);
                }

                else
                {
                    $('#feedback_body').html('<p>Error</p>');
                }




        }
```

but it does not work. What might be the reason?

Comment: are you having error or empty page  ???? If its error can you paste the error you are having

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you missed `});` in the end?